# Caching calculated values in functional languages - design problem

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming, architecture, f#

I'm relatively new to functional programming, as an exercise I'm trying to implement card game called 'addenda'. Problem I'm facing now is, as I think, exemplification of something more general.

To correctly implement some of the game rules I need some auxiliary data. This data can be stored in a state of the game, in my opinion polluting game model, or recalculated each time player action is made. So in my opinion this is kind of a trade off.

Now, in OO design I could implement such a component (let's name it ValueCalculator) using DI, injecting service that calculates needed value each time its needed, or simply inject some decorator that stores values in its internal cache, that is not seen from outer perspective. So I can achieve some degree of flexibility not polluting rest of the domain model, and exchange behavior without even recompiling core of the application - changes have to be made only in composition root.

Is there a way of achieving the same flexibility using purely functional constructs (I'm not counting classes, interfaces and mutable state here of course)?
How functional programmers deals with such cases?

Comment: Have you read about memoization?

Comment: Yes, but how exactly achieve my goals with it? Or You are referring to some kind of memoization especially suited for functional programming?

Comment: as soon as OO'ers start talking about dependency injection, then you should start thinking about partial functions (they're, with some hand waving, loosely equivalent). I need your example to be more explicit though. You say that some data is required by your algorithm, but you don't want to include it in the state required for that algorithm, because it will pollute...I would see that as a contradiction, if it is required, then it has to be part of the state, (pure) functional programming forces you to make all this state explicit

Comment: (thats not to say, you can't engineer it into nice lumps)

Comment: so...you could "inject" a function called "ValueCalculator"?

Comment: its the "storing of state" that is problematic?

Comment: Post a small portion of your code and I (or someone else) can show you how to apply memoization. But basically, `memoize` is a function that accepts a function and returns a version of the function that uses caching.

Comment: Thanks guys for Your comments, later I will provide more info or some code samples. Maybe, as You say, my requirements are self contradictory and these simply can't be achieved in pure fp. Maybe I wrongly thought that functional paradigm is the answer to all possible problems.

Comment: For now, let's say that i want to be able to change dynamically change two versions of algorithm - one with and other without caching and want that this change is not seen by the rest of the application, besides only the most outer layer - some kind of the configuration mechanism for dependencies. (in OO paradigm it is called composition root).